# Property 'x' not found on object of type 'const _strong id' Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a for loop like

```
for(id<SomeObj> in someClass.someListOfObjs){
   if(someObj.isSomeBoolean) { ... }
}
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Property "isSomeBoolean" not found on object of type 'const __strong id<SomeObj>'
```

Which is quite confusing. Why is this happening? Can I not iterate through a list of Id?

Comment: Is there a property `isSomeBoolean` declared in the `SomeObj` protocol?

Comment: @KenThomases, yes it is

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `SomeObj` protocol?